# :polymorphic/:through ActiveRecord associations (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many, polymorphic-associations

I have a tag system that can apply to various `Taggable`s. I want to be able to query them transparently, as in the accepted solution here:

[HABTM Polymorphic Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964678/habtm-polymorphic-relationship)

I want to be able to say, for example, show me all `Post`s, `Page`s, `Video`s, etc. tagged with 'foo'. Pretty straighforward. The complications:

1. The different kinds of `Taggable`s are not polymorphic in the OO sense, only through polymorphic associations. There *is* a `taggables` table to guarantee uniqueness of taggable_id (the primary key in `posts`, etc.).
2. `Tag`s, not surprisingly, have a many-to-many relation with `Taggable`s, and are associated through the `map_tags` table.

Models:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :map_tags
  has_many :tagged, :through => :map_tags
end

class MapTag < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :tags
  belongs_to :tagged, :polymorphic => :true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :map_tags, :as => :tagged 
  has_many :tags, :through => :map_tags
  # other taggables are set up similarly
end
```

Questions:

1. I guess my first questions ought to be: is this even possible? I have seen Models "have many" associated instances polymorphically, but I'm not sure if it works the other way, as the error message below may suggest...
2. Did I set up the polymorphism correctly? My understanding is that the "child" models basically declare themselves as "tagged", and whichever table interfaces with them directly (in this case `map_tags`) is the one to get the `:polymorphic` declaration.
3. How do I say "show me everything tagged with 'foo'" in ActiveRecord-speak?

What I've tried:

```
irb> Tag.find_by_name( 'foo', :include => :tagged )
Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'foo' LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant Tag::Tagged
...
irb> Tag.find( :all, :include => :tagged, :conditions => ["Tag.name = 'foo'"] )
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError:
Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Tag#tagged' on the polymorphic object 'Tagged#tagged'.
...
```

**EDIT**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997141/rails-has-many-through-with-polymorphic-association-will-this-work), which points out that I need to specify `:source` and `:source_type`. So:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :map_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :map_tags, :source => :tagged, :source_type => 'Post'
  has_many :pages, :through => :map_tags, :source => :tagged, :source_type => 'Page'
end
```

I think I'm closer(?), but I'm still not sure how to query the associated objects...

```
irb> Tag.first.posts
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `posts' for #<Tag id: 1, name: "foo">
irb> Tag.first.tagged
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError:
Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Tag#tagged' on the polymorphic object 'Tagged#tagged'.
```

Comment: silly but did you reload the console (I have a similar polymorphic relation and the has_many setup is correct) ?

Comment: I did reload the console and got the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your polymorphic association setup is correct. Except for a small typo :

```
belongs_to :tagged, :polymorphic => :true
```

It should be true the boolean not :true the symbol !