# Polymorphic Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having issue creating a nested polymorphic form. I am following the solution from this problem:

[Rails: has_many through with polymorphic association - will this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997141/rails-has-many-through-with-polymorphic-association-will-this-work)

The description was: A Person can have many Events and each Event can have one polymorphic Eventable record

Here are the relevant models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :eventable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event, :as => eventable
end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event, :as => eventable
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :meals, :through => :events, :source => :eventable,
    :source_type => "Meal"
  has_many :workouts, :through => :events, :source => :eventable,
    :source_type => "Workout"
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def 
  @person = Person.new
  @person.meals.new
  @person.workouts.new
new
```

My view looks like this:

```
<%=  form_for @person do |person| %>
 <%= person.fields_for :meals, @person.meals.build do |meals| %>
   <%= meals.text_field :food %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The error I am currently getting is:

**unknown attribute: person_id**

I would think that the polymorphic association is hindering the creation of the object because meals can't be create until person has been created? Did I set up the form correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `person_id` column as integer in `events` table? Also, I think controller code you've provided is mistyped maybe?

Comment: i think u dont need @person.meals.build

Comment: No, there isn't a person_id in the events table. Oh, how is it mistyped?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include a `person_id` attribute in the `events` table (as per the `belongs_to` association)

There are also some other issues you should resolve:

---

**Controller**

```
def new
    @person = Person.build
end

def create
    @person = Person.new(person_attributes)
    @person.save
end

private

def person_attributes
    params.require(:person).permit(:your, :attributes, events_attributes: [:eventable_type, :eventable_id, meal_attributes: [:params], workout_attributes: [:params]])
end
```

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/person.rb
Class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    has_many :meals, :through => :events, :source => :eventable,
        :source_type => "Meal"
    has_many :workouts, :through => :events, :source => :eventable,
        :source_type => "Workout"

    def self.build
        person = Person.new
        person.events.build.build_meal
        person.events.build.build_workout
    end

end
```

---

**Views**

```
#app/views/people/new.html.erb
<%=  form_for @person do |person| %>
 <%= person.fields_for :events do |e| %>
   <%= e.fields_for :meal %>
       <%= e.text_field :food %>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rich. Now I'm getting a unknown attribute: eventable_id. Is this because events is the polymorphic connection and needs to know Meal's id before it can create itself?